# Why Composite steps in jBehave doesn't execute pre-conditions first?

Tags: java, jbehave

I am automating my web application with JBehave where I face following issue.

I have created one composite steps which includes all the pre-conditions.. When I run the steps, it first executes what is inside the composite step rather than running pre-conditions first..

How can I run the tests sequentially by using composite steps. Please advise.

Following is my steps file code.

```
@Given("I see given step")
    public void given()
    {
        System.out.println("Inside GIVEN");
    }

    @Then("I see then step")
    public void when()
    {
        System.out.println("Inside WHEN");
    }

    @Then("I see when step")
    public void then()
    {
        System.out.println("Inside THEN");
    }

    @Given("I see composite step")
    @Composite(steps={"Given I see given step","Then I see then step","When I see when step"})
    public void composite()
    {
        System.out.println("Inside COMPOSITE");
    }
```

When I run "Given I see composite step", the sysout which is inside composite function runs first.. I need to execute the pre-conditions first.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The steps inside the @Composite are not meant as preconditions for the implementation of your @Composite-Annotated-Method...

If you are happy with Scenario/Story based pre-conditions you could consider the [JBehave Lifecycle](https://jbehave.org/reference/stable/lifecycle.html).

If you need pre-conditions at step bases (as you said) I would fake it, by adding a 4th JBehave step, that is called last in your @Composite block.

Given your example:

```
    @Given("I see given step")
    public void given()
    {
        System.out.println("Inside GIVEN");
    }

    @When("I see when step")
    public void then()
    {
        System.out.println("Inside THEN");
    }

    @Then("I see then step")
    public void when()
    {
        System.out.println("Inside WHEN");
    }

    @Then("your step executed last")
    public void then()
    {
        // logic from composite()
        System.out.println("Inside COMPOSITE");
    }

    @Given("I see composite step")
    @Composite(steps={"Given I see given step","When I see when step","Then I see then step","Then your step executed last"})
    public void composite()
    {
         //logic got moved
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to nest steps, I am fairly certain that JBehave was never designed to handle that scenario.  You have a minor typo in your code regardless, you have "@then" steps twice, one saying it's in "when." but I get what you were trying to do (I think).

You should leave the detailed, multiple-step steps together in the same @Given/@When/@Then/@And step.  There's no rule that says each step should only contain one line of code, but it should obviously only contain one compound step.

Hope this helps.  If not, please explain in more detail what you are attempting to accomplish, preferably with a real-life example.